# How does the Survival bonus work?

Tags: diablo-iii

Today, I was very badly injured and ran away from a combat for a few seconds. After a little while of flashing red health, I got an XP bonus called "Survival", telling me exactly what percentage of health I survived with and granting me some bonus XP.

How does this bonus work? What percentages is this for, how long do I have to be at those percentages, and how is the XP doled out?

Comment: Hmmmm I came back from around 60 health and saw no bonuses...

Comment: I was running around at low health for a few seconds. I've been at low health before, but I usually use a potion (or my templar heals me).

Comment: In the Halls of Agony I got caught in the fire and actually got two of these bonuses in a row - one said I had 1.5% HP left, and then I healed a bit and got nicked by the fire again and got one for 3.something%.  I'm willing to bet they only proc at 5% HP or lower.

Comment: @Shinrai Actually, I believe my bonus mentioned around 7% life, so it might be 10% or less.

Comment: @IanPugsley - Or that would be reasonable; I'm surprised I haven't hit another one yet, though!

Comment: http://i393.photobucket.com/albums/pp18/prodiii/random/Screenshot106.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can confirm that the life threshold is 10%.  I have received this bonus a great many times, and have gotten it at 9.9%, but never more than 10%.  You get the bonus when combat ends while you're below the life threshold.  Combat is considered to end when you get a certain distance away from monsters, *or* when you're already at a distance from all monsters and kill something.  This means that it's possible to get the bonus many times from a pack of monsters, by withdrawing at low health and then picking them off one at a time:  You'll get the bonus for each monster you kill.  I earned the Survivor achievement in less than an hour, in this way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there are any well-defined references out in the wild internets for the Survival Bonus yet, but I've received it as well.

It appears that the game can detect when you are "no longer in combat." That is, when all enemies within a certain radius are killed. If your life is **below 10%** (I've gotten a bonus at 9%, but not 10%) when you "leave" combat, you'll get the Survival Bonus.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten them for 5% and below, I haven't personally gotten any above that.

It appears the game awards the bonus for just getting damaged that low, and surviving for ~1 or 2 seconds. I've gotten bonuses for 1% health from when I have actually died from the damage within 2 seconds. Still in combat and etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have had numbers in the region of 10% to toggle the popup. Combat appears to end when there are no enemies left on your screen or you're fleeing from battle. I do not believe I've ever had an instance where this achievement has triggered above 10% health.